# Unitarily diagonalizable V.S. unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, unitary-matrices

We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. (so our vector space is finite dimensional.) We know that

> $A$ is *unitary* iff $AA^*=I=A^*A$ where $^*$ is conjugate transpose.

> $A$ is *normal* iff $AA^*=A^*A$.

In particular unitary matrices are normal.

> $A$ is *unitarily diagonalizable* iff there is a unitary matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix.

Question 1: Is unitarily diagonalizable the same as orthonormally diagonalizable in some books? I suppose unitary matrices are just orthonormal matrices with respect to the inner product $\langle v,w\rangle=v^*w$?

I am also quite confused between the unitary matrix and a matrix that is unitarily diagonalizable.
The spectral theorem states

> $A$ is normal iff $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable.

I think a corollary of spectral theorem is

> $A$ is unitary iff $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable and all eigenvalues having absolute value $1$.

Combining these results it seems we get

> $A$ is unitary iff $A$ is normal with all eigenvalues having absolute value $1$.

That is the distinction between unitary and unitarily diagonalizable matrices.

Question 2: Are the above statements correct? If not, could you provide an example.

Comment: In the above context, orthonormal usually means with respect to real matrices. Also look up the Schur decomposition (of matrices).

Comment: What you said are mostly correct. Just one remark, $\langle v, w\rangle=vw^*$ (usually one puts this for the purpose that the second component can be antilinear) does not provide an inner product simply because you will get a matrix instead of a number. So some may set the trace of this product to be the inner product of matrices. I guess what you wanted to say is perhaps to take the inner product of the column vectors in $v$ and the line vectors in $w^*$. In that case, the two notions coincide on the level of the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to my own question.

For the first question, we say

> $A$ is *orthogonal* if $A^tA=I=AA^t$.

> $A$ is *unitary* if $A^H A=I=A A^H$, where $H$ means conjugate transpose.

Therefore over $\mathbb{C}$ we usually do not use 'orthonormally' diagonalizable, but unitarily diagonalizable. In this language, there exist an orthonormal (w.r.t. the standard Hermitian inner product below) eigenbasis of $T$ iff $T$ is unitarily diagonalizable in spectral theorem.

---

There are two conventions of inner product, written vectors horizontally and vertically. Here we tend to use $\langle v,w\rangle=vw^H$.

---

For the second question, what I wrote is correct.